# For loop that references prior rows

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm interested in filtering out data based on a set of rules.

I have a dataset that contains play data for all games in which a team had a .8 win probability at some point. What I'd like to do is find that point in which the win probability reached .8 and remove every play thereafter until the next game data begins. The dataset contains numerous games so once a game ends data from a new one begins in which the win probability goes back to around .5.

Here are the relevant columns and each row is a play in the game:

- game_id = unique num for each game
- team = team that will eventually get an .8 win prob
- play_id = num that is increased (but not necessary in seq order for some reason) after each play
- win_per = num showing what the teams win percentage chance at the start of that recorded play was

Example df

```
df = data.frame(game_id = c(122,122,122,122,122,144,144,144,144,144),
team = c("a","a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","b","b"),
play_id = c(1,5,22,25,34, 45,47,55,58,66),
win_per = c(.5,.6,.86,.81,.85,.54,.43,.47,.81,.77))
```

So in this small example, I have recorded 5 plays of two teams (a and b) who both obtained a win_prob of at least .8 at some point in the game. In both example cases, I would want to have all the plays removed AFTER they attained this .8 mark regardless of whether the win_prob kept rising or fell back below .8.

So team a would have the final two rows of data removed (win_prob == .81 and .85) and team b would have the final row removed (win_prob = .77)

I'm imagining running a for loop that checks if the team in any row is the same team as the prior row, and if so, find a win_prob >= .8 with the lowest play-id (as this would be the first time the team reached .8) and then somehow remove the rest of the rows following that match UNTIL the team != prior row's team.

Of course, you might know a better way as well. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: i should note, play_id will restart for each recorded game so they don't keep continuing to be bigger numbers across the entire data set

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a loop, that whole selection can be performed in 1 line using the dplyr package:

```
df = data.frame(game_id = c(122,122,122,122,122,144,144,144,144,144),
                team = c("a","a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","b","b"),
                play_id = c(1,5,22,25,34, 45,47,55,58,66),
                win_per = c(.5,.6,.86,.81,.85,.54,.43,.47,.81,.77))


library(dplyr)
#group by team
#find the first row that exceeds .80 and add temp column
#save the row from 1 to the row that exceeds 0.80
#remove temp column
df %>% group_by(team, game_id) %>% 
       mutate(g80= min(which(win_per>=0.80))) %>% 
       slice(1:g80) %>% 
       select(-g80)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   team [2]
  game_id team  play_id win_per
    <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     122 a           1    0.5 
2     122 a           5    0.6 
3     122 a          22    0.86
4     144 b          45    0.54
5     144 b          47    0.43
6     144 b          55    0.47
7     144 b          58    0.81
```

Comment: So I think I found a bug in this. I didn't articulate that the same teams are recurring in this data many times for different games later in the season or following seasons, so the group_by is taking all of them together. Imagine team a vs team b in the example I gave and then somewhere down the line team a vs. team g or team b vs team r etc.

Comment: @JeffHenderson, if that is the case then `group_by(team, game_id)`, I made the edit up above to reflect the search per unique team and game id.

Comment: @JeffHenderson, Did the edit above answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way using `cumsum` in `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(win_per > 0.8, game_id, FUN = function(x) c(0, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])) == 0)

#  game_id team play_id win_per
#1     122    a       1    0.50
#2     122    a       5    0.60
#3     122    a      22    0.86
#6     144    b      45    0.54
#7     144    b      47    0.43
#8     144    b      55    0.47
#9     144    b      58    0.81
```

and using the similar concept in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(game_id) %>% filter(lag(cumsum(win_per > 0.8) == 0, default = TRUE))
```

Comment: this worked great! One more question. what would be the code if I want to do sort of the inverse? say I want to remove the rows leading up to the first row of win_per .3 or lower and keep everything else afterwards for that game_id?

Comment: @JeffHenderson In that case, you can do `df %>% group_by(game_id) %>% filter(cumsum(win_per > 0.3) != 0)`

Comment: this didn't seem to have worked, I'm still seeing rows before the win_per drops to .3 or lower. keep in mind that most of the first rows for win_per start around .5 or so and then eventually drop to .3 or lower before going back up. I"m hoping to remove all rows before win_per drops to .3 and keep that row with .3 plus everything row after per game_id.